# Capturing video using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am having an issue capturing the video feed, my camera light goes on and then off when i run this code. I tried using different values as well. And my camera seems to be working. but this code is not.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # zero instead of one

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if not ret: # exit loop if there was problem to get frame to display
        break

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: @J.D. please no. this code, as is, is good (except for the missing test of `assert cap.isOpened()` or similar). there is no point in staying in the loop if `ret` is false even just once. a single failed read **usually** means it's over. there is no reason to expect that to fail just intermittently. that's a fundamental assumption in much of that module of OpenCV.

Comment: Is your Python and OpenCV up to date? Does the code work if you substitute the `0` with the path to a video file?